# Can copyright of an open sourced product be passed down through generations?

Tags: copyright, ownership

**Background:**

From other posts I have learned that copyrights expire some amount of time after the owner's death. But from what I know ownership can be passed on after death. If the owner of a copyright hands over the ownership (through a will or other means) does that mean that the copyright will now expire after the aforementioned amount of time after this person's death?

Comment: I'm voting to close this because it is not about open source, but rather about copyright. This is not a question that will come up mainly when dealing with open source either.

Comment: I have changed it @overactor to better fit open source

Comment: @TrevorClarke we're faring into [boat programming](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14470/what-is-the-boat-programming-meme-about) waters here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this because it is not about open source, but primarily about copyright. It would be a much better candidate for Law.SE

Answer (score 4):

No, the copyright term is x year after the creators death, not after the current owners death.

Comment: More than "Oh boy, international copyright term, well, it's a sad and long tale of international intrigue, Sonny Bono, and Somalian Pirates"?